# Fast Fourier Transform for varying period (Order analysis)

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, frequency

I am trying to do a fast Fourier transformation on accelerometer data from a shaft rotating at varying speed.

**What I have done so far:**

**1: The original plot was in the time domain, and I therefore did a order analysis (resampled), and got the following plot:**
[image]

This plot shows the angular rotation plotted against amplitude.

**2: Now, an FFT was done with this code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

class FastFourierTransform:
    # Amplitudes is a row vector
    def __init__(self, amplitudes, t):
        self.s = amplitudes
        self.t = t

    # Plotting in the input domain before fft
    def plot_input(self):
        plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
        plt.xlabel("Shaft angle [Radians]")
        plt.plot(self.t, self.s)
        plt.margins(0)
        plt.show()

        '''
        The second half of this array of fft sequence have similar frequencies
        since the frequency is the absolute value of this value.
        '''
    def fft_transform(self):
        mean_amplitude = np.mean(self.s)
        self.s = self.s - mean_amplitude # Centering around 0
        fft = np.fft.fft(self.s)

        # We now have the fft for every timestep in out plot.

        # T is the sample frequency in the data set
        T = self.t[1] - self.t[0] # This is true when the period between each sample in the time waveform is equal
        N = self.s.size  # size of the amplitude vector
        f = np.linspace(0, 1 / T, N, )  # start, stop, number of. 1 / T = frequency is the bigges freq
        plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
        plt.xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")
        y = np.abs(fft)[:N // 2] * 1 /N

        # Cutting away half of the fft frequencies.

        sns.lineplot(f[:N // 2], y) # N // 2 is normalizing it
        plt.margins(0)
        plt.show()
        time = f[:N // 2]
        return fft, time
```

**3. Result, with the normalized amplitudes plotted:**
[image]

**Questions:**

1. Does this thought process look correct?
2. Is it correct to say that the final fft plot is in the *frequency* domain? From this link, http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372416L-01/svtconcepts/svcompfftorder/, it looks like the final plot domain should be in the order domain, but I am not sure since the fft was 
   done from the radian domain.

*Vibration- Based Condition Monitoring of Wind Turbines* by Tomasz Barszcz has this image [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please look up minimal example. You didn't provide any data, therefore people cannot follow.   How did you get the shaft angle? The accelerometer alone will provide data as function of time. The FFT of that is the vibration spectrum. Unless you also recorded angle of the shaft over time (you said the rotational speed was changing)  you can't plot the acceleration (which one, x,y,z, absolute value?) over angle.

Comment: The FFT of the vibration as function of shaftangle could be called 'order domain', as it plots the vibrations as multiples of roundtrips, so the first order should be for one roundtrip, higher 'order' vibrations would be two per roundtrip and so on.

Comment: The image appears to be incorrect in the bottom left. There it should show a sine of fixed frequency (the FFT is a delta, after all), with the x-axis as angle and the datapoints at unequal intervals.

Comment: The same thing would be true for your original (evenly sampled time) data of acceleration. To get to data as function of angle, you will have unevenly sampled angles. Whether those can be interpolated well needs to be shown (sampling theorem). Only once you have evenly spaced data can you use the FFT to get to the order spectrum.

Comment: You could apply a low pass filter as the signal is resampled as advised in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/593/how-do-i-take-the-fft-of-unevenly-spaced-data . Indeed, it would limit [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AliasingSines.svg). Therefore, convoluting the signal with a triangle of width consistent with the resampling rate could be helpful. Finally, it could be necessary to apply a window prior to the FFT if the original signal contains frequencies that are not consistent with the rotation period.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers!